# accessing my system in home from my office

Tags: networking

what are all the possible ways of using remote desktop through internet....i was asked to do this without installing vnc and just by routing the router...is this possible...i dont think so...please explain me

Answer (score 0):

We need more information to answer your question:

1) What type of Internet connection do you have at home? Does it have a static IP address?

2) What kind of router/firewall device do you have?

Generically:

1) You need to forward port 3389 to your desktop.

2) Your desktop should probably have an internal static IP address so the port forward never breaks, you might be able to do this with a DHCP reservation as well.

3) If your external IP address is not static, you may need to use a dynamic DNS server to sync a public DNS record with your current IP.

4) You need to enable the remote desktop service on the desktop under System Properties.